# How to create tile images for tiled maps using ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, map-service

I am a newbie to ArcGIS Online. I have to create a temperature tile map based on my own custom data. I have found that a tile layer can be added using the following link:

http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/tile-layers.htm

Adding a new ArcGIS tile layer uses a service request like

(http://{subDomain}.tile.opencyclemap.org/cycle/{level}/{col}/{row}.png)

to get specific images from service for specific zoom levels, the question is how and where these images will be created based on our own data?

Is there any tool that creates such images for storage purpose and later to utilize using service call?

Can we create these images dynamically at run time based on our own data and how?
We want to create the end product like:
http://maps.google.com/gallery/details?id=zttWLnOPAlrs.kQBKSYw5ok5U&hl=en

Comment: What software do you have locally -- ArcMap? Is your data currently in points or a raster? Do you have the heatmap yet or not? As a short answer to the last part of your question, using tiles will only allow you to show a _static image_ and if you want to instead have the map draw the heat map when displaying, that's a different sort of map service.

Comment: Generally, map tiling is done with ArcGIS Server and your own server machine to hold all the cached images.  Having Esri's ArcGIS Online cloud storage hold your cached images could be prohibitive if your rasters are fairly large.  That being said, after you have created a feature service in ArcGIS Online, you can publish it as a tiled service later.

Comment: Erica, I need to draw plenty of Maps like wind maps with point data, soil maps, temperature maps. I am successfully able to draw heat maps from point data using ArcGIS for JavaScript. However, if I have got point temperature data of say 5 locations in a city. Does any ArcGIS tool allow me to automatically create images from that data taking care of all boundaries or I have to manually create tile images? 

Does it take a geologist to create tiles and use ArcMap or Programmers with some GIS experience on simple location based maps can also create maps like ones mentioned in the link of question

Comment: It is possible (albeit potentially expensive for "plenty of maps") to build tiles in ArcGIS Online: see [this blog describing workflows](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/02/06/workflows-for-building-and-hosting-cached-map-tiles-in-arcgis/): "if you decide to build the tiles in ArcGIS Online, you use the File > Share As > Service wizard in ArcMap to define your cache"

Answer (score 2):

Tile Packages are your friend. You can upload them to AGOL and create a Hosted Tile Services from them.